# Copy Multiple Images From Remote Server

Tags: php

I am trying to copy multiple images from a remote host (using a URL) to my local box (using XAMPP on my local box to execute the script).

I am using `copy()`.  When I go to execute the `copy()`, only the LAST image in the array is created.  So, if I have 5 image links, only the 5th image gets created and nothing prior even gets a file created.

I have tried `CURL` and `FOpen` and then both create all of the files, but all of the files are blank except, again, the last file which is perfectly fine.

```
$txt_file = file_get_contents('urls_for_images.txt');
if(!empty($txt_file)){
   $image_links = explode("\n", $txt_file);

   $i = 1;     
   foreach($image_links as $image_link){
     $file_info = pathinfo($image_link);
     copy($image_link, 'images/00' . $i . '_original.' . $file_info['extension']);
     $i++;
   }
}
```

I am not sure where the problem is occurring, but it seems odd to me that it will copy the last image in the text file, but not any of the others.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The i variable never changes, therefore the code tries to copy a file with the same name over and over again and only the last file is saved.
Try modifying your code this way:

```
$txt_file = file_get_contents('urls_for_images.txt');

if(!empty($txt_file)){
   $image_links = explode("\n", $txt_file);

   $i = 1;
   foreach($image_links as $image_link){
      $file_info = pathinfo($image_link);
      copy($image_link, 'images/00' . $i . '_original.' . $file_info['extension']);
      $i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: I missed adding the '$i++' when I copied my code over to here.  It is in my code on my machine and that is not the problem.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off with just `file()`, which reads the file into an array automatically:

```
$files = file('urls_for_images.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($files as $remote_file) {
   $local_file = ....;
   copy($remote_file, $local_file);
}
```

Comment: can give a try to this copy (trim($tmp_name),$destination));

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is the text file which line endings are `\r\n` and you are exploding with only `\n`. The quickest way to fix this is either `explode` by `\r\n`; or `trim` with default parameters to remove `\r` from the end of each line.

```
   foreach($image_links as $image_link){
     $image_link = trim($image_link);
     $file_info = pathinfo($image_link);
     ...
   }
```

However, the cleanest way to do this is to use [**file function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), which handles line endings automatically. I recommend you to use this approach.